# android facebook what is privacy policy url?

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an android app.
It first asks permission(publish_actions) if it is okey it shares a bitmap image from my app.
In developers.facebook page, It requires privacy policy url. Do I have to add one? I am not using any information of users just checking if they are allowed my app after they login.If I have to, what is this privact policy?

Do I have to pay money to facebook because ı am using their sdk?

Can I use facebook icons?

Answer (score 1):

If you share an image, you will need to have activated `(publish_actions)` ,because it is necesary for lets people post to Facebook using a custom composer, Publishes Open Graph stories or Publishes content to Facebook automatically.

So, to ask for approval of this permission is required  have a url containing your Privacy Policy, but you can generate in  http://www.generateprivacypolicy.com/,  http://www.iubenda.com/.

you don't have to pay  for use SDK

Comment: It wants me to write my website url? then asks what am i doint with users info with my website?

Comment: in my case I used only to generate www.iubenda.com, after that copied in html and uploaded to my website server.  .. your appp have a website?

Comment: No. I am going to upload it google store.What should i do?